# How to center tabs with CSS and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a centered tabs on my web page. I tried several solutions found on this site but it does not work well with me.

I used the tabs as buttons and It is a full page tabs. 
My code is simple and I also added comments to better understand.
Here is my snippet code below I hope you will help me.

```js
function openPage(evt, pageName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Show current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
/* Full page tabs */
body,html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
}
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #03A9F5;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
/* Style the buttons */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 24%;
}
/* Background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    color: #E1FBFF;
}
/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Tab links -->
<div class="tab">
  <button id="defaultOpen" class="tablinks" onclick="openPage(event, 'tab1')">TAB1</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openPage(event, 'tab2')">TAB2</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openPage(event, 'tab3')">TAB3</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tab1</h3>
</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tab2</h3>
</div>
<div id="tab3" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tab3</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want tabs justified to the width?

Comment: If you're gonna style with a border you might wanna add something like `border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;` to `.tab button` so they don't bounce around when the active border switches from one tab to another

Comment: You can use flex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update this part of your css

```
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #03A9F5;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    text-align:center; /*add this to center the buttons*/
}
/* Style the buttons */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    /*float: left;*/ /*remove floats*/
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 24%;
     border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;/*Add this to prevent flickering/jumping*/
}
```

```js
function openPage(evt, pageName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Show current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
/* Full page tabs */
body,html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
}
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #03A9F5;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    text-align:center;
}
/* Style the buttons */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    /*float: left;*/
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 24%;
     border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}
/* Background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    color: #E1FBFF;
}
/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Tab links -->
<div class="tab">
  <button id="defaultOpen" class="tablinks" onclick="openPage(event, 'tab1')">TAB1</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openPage(event, 'tab2')">TAB2</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openPage(event, 'tab3')">TAB3</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tab1</h3>
</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tab2</h3>
</div>
<div id="tab3" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tab3</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to align content nowadays is usually to use ["Flexbox"](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) - and in this case `justify-content`.

```
.tab {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; // centers its children
}
```

```js
function openPage(evt, pageName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Show current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
/* Full page tabs */
body,html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
}
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #03A9F5;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
/* Style the buttons */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 24%;
}
/* Background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    color: #E1FBFF;
}
/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Tab links -->
<div class="tab">
  <button id="defaultOpen" class="tablinks" onclick="openPage(event, 'tab1')">TAB1</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openPage(event, 'tab2')">TAB2</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openPage(event, 'tab3')">TAB3</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tab1</h3>
</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tab2</h3>
</div>
<div id="tab3" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tab3</h3>
</div>
```

---

You could also use `justify-content: space-around` if you want the tabs centered but distributed around, or take a look at [some of its other values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).

Comment: did you change only .tab { ... } class ?  I also tried `justify-content: space-around;` and did not work form me.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for?

```js
function openPage(evt, pageName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Show current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
/* Full page tabs */
body,html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
}
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #03A9F5;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
/* Style the buttons */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: inherit;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 24%;
}
/* Background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    color: #E1FBFF;
}
/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<center>
    <!-- Tab links -->
    <div class="tab">
      <button id="defaultOpen" class="tablinks" onclick="openPage(event, 'tab1')">TAB1</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openPage(event, 'tab2')">TAB2</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openPage(event, 'tab3')">TAB3</button>
    </div>
    </center>

    <!-- Tab content -->
    <div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Tab1</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Tab2</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tabcontent">
      <h3>Tab3</h3>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks. can you indicate what change did you make in the code?

Comment: I added <center> tag to your HTML and float: center to your css

Comment: but CSS float property does not have "center" value. The CSS Syntax
`float: none | left | right | initial | inherit;`

Comment: just put anything you want because <center> makes everything centered